# Why my AVD Manager dont lauch anything? ADT v22.2.1-833290

Tags: java, android, eclipse

Well I just downloaded everything today to get started programming on android. Files Downloaded: *Java JRE and JDK*, both latest versions. And *ADT Bundle* (unzipped in a folder).

In the process running "Myfirstapp" I got stuck trying to launch AVD, no idea why it is not working.
(`Device: 2.7" QVGA--Target:Android 4.3 - API level 18--default everything else`)

After created the new AVD, I clicked start then the launch windows appears and nothing happened, no error message also.

If I try to run the app directly using "run as: Android Application" i got this on the 
Cosole:

```
[2013-11-02 20:26:35 - MySECAPP] ------------------------------
[2013-11-02 20:26:35 - MySECAPP] Android Launch!
[2013-11-02 20:26:35 - MySECAPP] adb is running normally.
[2013-11-02 20:26:35 - MySECAPP] Performing com.example.mysecapp.MainActivity activity launch
[2013-11-02 20:26:41 - MySECAPP] Launching a new emulator with Virtual Device 'NUEVO'
```

Comment: Are you waiting until the AVD finishes it's booting?

Comment: Yup I waited long enough. On the task manager the process(Emulator-arm.exe) show up for a while and then it just disappears...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi guys I just wanted to say that I solved My problem updating my videocard driver(ATI Radeon HD 5450).